# QML saying file import is not found

Tags: qml, qt-creator, importerror

I'm writing a project in QML using QT Creator. My dir looks like this:
[image]

Inside `transactions.qml` I'm trying to import in `TrsInputField.qml`, which contains a simple InputField component.

At the start of `transactions.qml` I have tried:

`import "TrsInputField.qml`

`import "qrc:\\TrsInputField.qml`

`import "qrc:\TrsInputField.qml`

`import "qrc://TrsInputField.qml`

But none of these work. Qt Creator does not give an error for file not found, but when I try to run the code, it says `"TrsInputField.qml": no such directory`

QT Creator is updated to newest version and I'm running MacOs Venture 13.1

Comment: You don't import individual files with QML. You import directories or modules. In your case, since the file you want is in the same directory you're calling it from, you don't need an import at all.

Comment: @JarMan is correct. If `TrsInputField` implements a valid QML component, it can be used in `transactions.qml`. You do not require an explicit `import` since both files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, as the comments pointed out components in the same folder do not need to be imported.